# Jurassic Park - Classic Roar

Tags: jurassic-park, techniques, sound-design, sound-effects

Curious. Do any of you know exactly what went into that sound? I've heard a variety of things, namely elephants, lions and washing machines; I imagine it might be a combination of all three.

~Cheers
Miles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rumor I heard is that it was a baby elephant that had been taken away from it's mother... Don't know how true that is...

Gary says one element is a Koala Bear. Other elements are lions, tigers, alligators, and yes a baby elephant from Marine World. He used a whale's blowhole for the breathing.

Then he loaded them all on a synclav and played them so they were in the same key. This made them mesh well together.

I also know that the Veloceraptor is a walrus and dolphin scream mixed together.

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried analysing it to find out for yourself?

Sample the roar/s off the DVD and pitch up half an octave or an octave 
& see what it reminds you of.... try playing it backwards etc...

if someone tells you the answer you learn very little.... 
if you discover it for yourself you learn a LOT!

Answer (score 8):

They went out and recorded a T-Rex.... duuuuuuuuhh..........

.

.

.

.

.

But seriously,

Ryan is right.  Koala bear, alligator, a whale, lizards, etc...

Here's a great interview with Gary about it:

[Gary Rydstrom on Jurassic Park](http://www.mpse.org/education/bigmovierydstrom.html)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.mpse.org/education/bigmovierydstrom.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwWvO4UgJiU
[youtube]qwWvO4UgJiU[/youtube]

Answer (score 4):

I'm interested to know as well, but I have to say: Some secrets are better left unexplained. :)

Answer (score 4):

Aside from what sounds went into creating the T-Rex roar (which is one of my favorite movie sounds ever - Gary Rydstrom FTW!) is how it was mixed. Whether intentional or not, and I'm guessing it was, the roaring is distorted, almost as though the dino would have overloaded the mic on the set or the mixer wouldn't have been able to adjust for it. The only thing I would have done differently to emphasize this overloading effect would be to side-chain the roar to a heavy compression on the other tracks. I've always wanted to try that on monsters, bullets, explosions, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I believe sea birds were also used to create the raptor sounds

Jurassic Park has my favourite creature sound design, brilliant sounding film :)

Answer (score 3):

I heard or read somewhere that one of the main elements was a recording of an aircraft simulator at NASA research facility. I've listened quite closely to these sounds and there is a machine-like tonality in there.

Answer (score 1):

I thought that the on-set recordist just made wild tracks with the dinosaurs while they were shooting...

Comment: No. T-Rex wanted to get paid extra for ADR.

Comment: Pfff...not to mention the velociraptors. They are full of themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recent article about Jurassic Park sound design:

http://www.vulture.com/2013/04/how-the-dino-sounds-in-jurassic-park-were-made.html