# Creating sounds for a T-Rex?

Tags: t-rex, design

Ive been given the task to create sounds for a T-Rex, and this is my first real sound design project. Im more accustomed to designing sounds with synthesis, not so much with recorded sounds, so I was hoping to get some pointers.

I have to make sounds for roaring and swallowing.

Any tips? :):)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A heavily slowed down **dog bark** could be a start, but you need some power with something like a **cow/bull**. Some sort of **hiss/wind** as well, because this thing must project quite a lot of air! An **elephant** could help and why not a **siren** (WW2 kind of bombing alert).

This is just brain storming, I might come back with more! :)

EDIT: revving up an **engine** could add character to the roar?

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! That is a good start. I have a library of stock sounds that Ive been playing around with and so far Ive used 2 leopard growls and a horse breathing heavily for the air. I think Im getting a nice start with the roar. 

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you've seen this question or not, but there are insights on how the Jurassic Park dinosaur roars where created: [Jurassic Park - Classic Roar](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/934/jurassic-park-classic-roar)

Comment: Ohhh wow, I havent seen this, but it is very helpful! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Mix in a screaming/squealing pig...or many of them.. and play around with the pitch!

Answer (score 1):

Tim Prebble's seal noise library over at www.hissandaroar.com could help you out here. I know Chuck Russom heavily recommends this library!

Joe

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could lean on some of the evolutionary theories regarding dinosaurs being predecessors to modern-day birds? Work with hawk screeches, falcons, crows, ravens, vultures, all manner of raptors, etc? There are also alligators and crocodiles to examine, seeing as how they seem to have remained pretty much the same since prehistory.

Answer (score 0):

i used a gorilla roar with some equing...in my Ice age 3 trailer project.. cause it was just a few secs long
http://www.4shared.com/get/ghBpP9Au/Audio_Post_Production-Sound_De.html

Answer (score 0):

Recordings of maggots in a box of crap might be a good start for the swallowing

Comment: For the roaring, you could work with some kind of air raid siren


Answer (score 0):

Try pitching down a Komodo dragon.

http://www.hark.com/clips/pjxshzhnnh-komodo-dragon

I think that your nearest ones are in LA Zoo.

http://lazoo.org/animals/reptiles/komododragon/index.html