# How to make iron man Sounds? :)

Tags: sound, inspiration, trailer

i need to record all the sounds of iron man 3 trailer, its homework,, i just need some ideas of how to record the sounds or design them :D.

Here is the video:

i would appreciate all ur anwswers.

Atte:
Luis ;)

Comment: Listen to the sounds, what do they sound like, what sounds could they be or where could they be from? Try listening to the soundtrack without the image for a clearer impression of what the soundtrack and the sound effects really consist of. Then, go figure.

Answer (score 2):

i had to do a similar thing whilst in University. The best advice i can give you is to listen critically to what you are trying to recreate. Try and work out how these sounds are achieved, and what they could be obtained from. Then experiment recording different mechanical and electrical sounds; printers, windows, microwaves, oven doors slamming literally anything you can find. Once you've done this, start pitching the sounds you have recorded up and down, layer them, combine them with synthesized elements, run them through different effect chains.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to defer to Tim Prebble's answer here: [Jurassic Park - Classic Roar](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/934/jurassic-park-classic-roar)

Especially so because you mention that this is homework.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Hi there,

Another good link on how they got some of the sounds for the film is:

http://www.soundworkscollection.com/news/why-the-iron-man-3-sound-department-went-to-toys-r-us

Quite an interesting article on how they got the sounds for the characters.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

For the sound of his hand laser weapon it starts with the sound of a camera's flash charging up. Then uses basic mechanical sounds to match his movements as well as metal bangs for impact. What are you looking for exactly?